# Shaking off duplicates while parsing

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I've made a parser written in python which is doing it's job perfectly except for some duplicates coming along. Moreover, when I open csv file I can see that every result is surrounded by square braces. Is there any workaround to get rid of duplicates data and square braces on the fly? Here is what I tried with:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html
def parsingdata(mpg):
    data = set()
    outfile=open('RealYP.csv','w',newline='')
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["Name","Address","Phone"])
    pg=1
    while pg<=mpg:
        url="https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page="+str(pg)
        page=requests.get(url)
        tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="info"]')
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            comb = []
            Name = title.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()')
            Address = title.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress" and @class="street-address"]/text()')
            Phone = title.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="telephone" and @class="phones phone primary"]/text()')
            try:
                comb.append(Name[0])
                comb.append(Address[0])
                comb.append(Phone[0])
            except:
                continue
            items.append(comb)

        pg+=1 
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow(item)
parsingdata(3)
```

Now it is working fine.
Edit: Rectified portion taken from bjpreisler

Comment: Without reading your code: The canonical solution to discard duplicates is to use a set which holds all seen values. Before doing anything with the next value you come along, check whether it's in the set.

Comment: Thanks sir timgeb, for your answer. Gonna try to implement what you just said but I'm a newbie so sometimes hard to maintain guideline accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Dear sir timgeb, I tried to follow what you said but this time it produces unhashable type: 'list' error.

Comment: Store a hashable type, the corresponding tuple or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently writing a list (items) to the csv which is why it is in brackets.  To avoid this, use another for loop that could look like this:

```
 for title in titles:
        comb = []
        Name = title.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()')
        Address = title.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress" and @class="street-address"]/text()')
        Phone = title.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="telephone" and @class="phones phone primary"]/text()')
        if Name:
            Name = Name[0]
        if Address:
            Address = Address[0]
        if Phone:
            Phone = Phone[0]
        comb.append(Name)
        comb.append(Address)
        comb.append(Phone)
        print comb
        items.append(comb)

pg+=1 
for item in items:
    writer.writerow(item)
parsingdata(3)
```

This should write each item separately to your csv.  It turns out the items you were appending to comb were lists themselves, so this extracts them.

Comment: Hi bjpreisler, thanks for your answer. I applied what you just suggested. It does clear square braces but all results come into a single column rather than three columns.

Comment: @SMth80, I edited the above code which should fix the problem!

Comment: Thanks  bjpreisler, it does the job. Btw, can you suggest me how could i use set() properly to avoid duplicates in this case.

Comment: Are you hoping to eliminate duplicates of name ('Starbucks') or just when the full item (Name, Address, Phone) is a duplicate?

Comment: Nope not that. Having scraped five pages when I click the option "remove duplicates" from csv file it removes some amount of duplicates. However going through the data I could notice that it did scrape some items with the same value across. Starbucks is a different case cause you know it although gets the same name but the addresses and phone numbers it contains are different from each other. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I guessed.  Okay, then I would forget set() because it doesn't work nicely with lists and just use NOT IN :

if comb not in items:
                items.append(comb)

Answer (score 3):

This script removes dups when I am working with a .csv file. Check if this works for you :)

```
with open(file_out, 'w') as f_out, open(file_in, 'r') as f_in:
    # write rows from in-file to out-file until all the data is written
    checkDups = set() # set for removing duplicates
    for line in f_in:
        if line in checkDups: continue # skip duplicate
        checkDups.add(line)
        f_out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

And the concise version of this scraper I found lately is:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={0}"

def parsingdata(link):

    outfile=open('YellowPage.csv','w',newline='')
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["Name","Address","Phone"])

    for page_link in [link.format(i) for i in range(1, 4)]:
        page = requests.get(page_link).text
        tree = html.fromstring(page)

        for title in tree.xpath('//div[@class="info"]'):
            Name = title.findtext('.//span[@itemprop="name"]')
            Address = title.findtext('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]')
            Phone = title.findtext('.//div[@itemprop="telephone"]')
            print([Name, Address, Phone])
            writer.writerow([Name, Address, Phone])

parsingdata(url)
```